# tinymce getContent function doean't returns empty head

Tags: tinymce

If I use the debugger and look inside the tinymce iframe, I see my head information that as loaded. But when I call tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'}), the head element comes back empty. I have added "fullpage" to the plugins as others have suggested.

It appears that tinymce is replacing the head element I gave it with its own and then dropping that before sending it back to me.

The problem is that I'm editing a complete HTML document and need teh head elements back.

Is this not possible with tinymce? Do I need different options in the .init()

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle showing your exact code and configuration of TinyMCE? Without seeing exactly what you are doing we will effectively be guessing how to help.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here's my initialization:

Comment: I get a web page from the server using ajax and put it in a variable. Then I set the content like this: tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(contents, {format : 'raw'});

And though the variable 'contents' has the head elements, if I change nothing and then call tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'}) the elements I originally saw in the head element are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Fiddle showing how this normally works:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/3Bfaab

Note that the HEAD content is preserved so if you are not seeing it preserved its something tied to your specific setup.

Comment: Thanks but when I run that same code, I get an error saying get isn't a function. Is this with V4?

Comment: Yes this is V4.  Its been in market for over 3 years now and V3 is getting no ongoing development.  If you are trying to implement TinyMCE V3 I would recommend that you move to V4.

Comment: I get a web page from the server using ajax and put it in a variable. Then I set the content like this: tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(contents, {format : 'raw'}); And though the variable 'contents' has the head elements, if I change nothing and then call tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'}) the elements I originally saw in the head element are gone

Comment: What is your configuration for TinyMCE?  Is the HTML you want to load a full complete web page with HEAD and BODY portions?

Comment: plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern fullpage"
   ],

Comment: At this point you have some issue specific to your code - can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows the process of loading the content and then console logging out the `getContent()` that does not include the HEAD elements?  Effectively I cannot get this same behavior so its specific to your TinyMCE configuration or how you are loading / extracting the content - without code I can't really offer more advice.